# Magento 2 how to receive a webhook body?

Tags: magento2, controllers, webapi, post-data

I'm doing an integration with a system called Sift Science.

What I need to accomplish is to receive a response whenever someone in Sift Science performs an action (for example> Approve account, ban account).

I can set web-hook URL in the service, but I don't how to receive the response.

I tried to receive it in a controller , because as far as I know web-hooks sends posts with json format, please correct me if i'm wrong.

In web-hook URL I set the controller path, and I'm using the following method to receive it>

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

But had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your webhooks there is a way to send parameters.If you are sending parameters then u can directly call 
$post = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); in your controller.